# Excel VBA: multiple if then statements?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I'm analyzing  survey responses and just want to recode them from the assigned numerical value back to their original meanings using a command button (is this even the most efficient format?). I'd like to escape the tedium of lots of clicking and "Find/Replace". Here's a sample of what I'm working with:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim response As Integer, result As String
response = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A58").Value

    If response = 1 Then result = "Individual Public School"
    ...
    If response = 8 Then result = "Museum (or other science-rich institution)"

ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B58").Value = result

End Sub
```

Excel is stopping me at the third line, prompting me with a debug option. Where am I going wrong? Is there a more elegant solution for this?

I'm on a Mac computer, and I'm using Microsoft Office 2010 version, if this helps at all.

Any and all tips are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: you are filling **response** like an array, but using it like a non-array variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    For Each r In Range("A3:A58")
        If r.Value = 1 Then r.Offset(0, 1) = "Individual Public School"
        '...
        If r.Value = 8 Then r.Offset(0, 1) = "Museum (or other science-rich institution)"
    Next r
End Sub
```